# Firestore is only loading limited data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Everything was working fine until I woke up one day with this problem, The app is only loading a limited number of documents and not the full query even though it was working perfectly a couple days ago? and these documents are the same documents it loads everytime even if I change the query so `query.where()` doesn't even work anymore. please note that all my other firebase services like FirebaseAuth and Firebase Functions are working fine.

Here's what I tried :

1 - `flutter clean`

2 - I updated all my firebase dependencies

3 - I looked for solutions everywhere but it doesn't seem like anyone faced this problem before?

Here's how my debug console looks like :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on 21121119SG in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\morsv\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.15.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\morsv\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_app_check-0.2.1+16\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\appcheck\FlutterFirebaseAppCheckPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\morsv\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.7.18\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
W/BpBinder( 2596): Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 297 ms, interface=com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.IMeasurementService, code=11 oneway=false
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:64862/A5sBxNaNAyQ=/ws
I/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Background concurrent copying GC freed 39546(1786KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(1160KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 5559KB/10MB, paused 91us total 149.073ms
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out( 2596): [socket]:check permission begin!
I/System.out( 2596): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/Android: [Awesome Notifications]( 2596): Channel model 'basic_channel' was not found (ChannelManager:88)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]( 2596): Notification channel Basic notifications created (ChannelManager:214)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]( 2596): Awesome Notifications initialized (AwesomeNotifications:440)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]( 2596): Awesome Notifications Flutter plugin initialized (AwesomeNotificationsPlugin:1388)
W/DynamiteModule( 2596): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 2596): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 2596): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): ClassLoaderContext classpath size mismatch. expected=1, found=0 (PCL[/system/framework/miui.services.jar*2958366392] | PCL[])
I/System.out( 2596): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out( 2596): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out( 2596): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out( 2596): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
V/NativeCrypto( 2596): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 295 native methods...
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 2596): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/System.out( 2596): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=10041 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
D/ProfileInstaller( 2596): Installing profile for net.bookdoor.book_door
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/ion     ( 2596): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
E/flutter ( 2596): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 2596): #0      _OnbordingState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:book_door/managers/boarding_screen.dart:105:67)
E/flutter ( 2596): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1203:30)
E/flutter ( 2596): #2      _OnbordingState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:book_door/managers/boarding_screen.dart:103:35)
E/flutter ( 2596): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2596):
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
D/DecorView[]( 2596): getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
V/PhoneWindow( 2596): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@7d22ada, this = DecorView@c26db0b[MainActivity]
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]( 2596): App is now Background (LifeCycleManager:94)
I/FA      ( 2596): Application backgrounded at: timestamp_millis: 1709884933638
V/PhoneWindow( 2596): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@7d22ada, this = DecorView@c26db0b[MainActivity]
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]( 2596): App is now Foreground (LifeCycleManager:94)
V/PhoneWindow( 2596): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@7d22ada, this = DecorView@c26db0b[MainActivity]
D/SurfaceView( 2596): UPDATE Surface(name=SurfaceView - net.bookdoor.book_door/net.bookdoor.book_door.MainActivity)/@0x521abe5, mIsProjectionMode = false
I/FirebaseAuth( 2596): Logging in as support@bookdoor.net with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  ( 2596): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 2596): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out( 2596): [socket]:check permission begin!
I/System.out( 2596): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
W/System  ( 2596): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 2596): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out( 2596): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out( 2596): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/FirebaseAuth( 2596): Notifying id token listeners about user ( TSUC8zwsmLPrAVHmdJpQHpYcRNA3 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 2596): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( TSUC8zwsmLPrAVHmdJpQHpYcRNA3 ).
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
D/DecorView[]( 2596): getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
I/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Compiler allocated 4379KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
E/flutter ( 2596): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _MyAccountState#e5f00(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 2596): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 2596): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 2596): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 2596): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1167:9)
E/flutter ( 2596): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1202:6)
E/flutter ( 2596): #2      _MyAccountState.refresh (package:book_door/pages/my_account.dart:68:5)
E/flutter ( 2596): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2596):
E/flutter ( 2596): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _CouponButtonState#03a1c(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 2596): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 2596): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 2596): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 2596): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1167:9)
E/flutter ( 2596): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1202:6)
E/flutter ( 2596): #2      _CouponButtonState.checkCouponButton (package:book_door/pages/cart.dart:154:7)
E/flutter ( 2596): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2596):
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/AssistStructure( 2596): Flattened final assist data: 456 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
E/flutter ( 2596): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _CouponButtonState#98ba3(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 2596): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 2596): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 2596): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 2596): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1167:9)
E/flutter ( 2596): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1202:6)
E/flutter ( 2596): #2      _CouponButtonState.checkCouponButton (package:book_door/pages/cart.dart:154:7)
E/flutter ( 2596): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2596):
E/flutter ( 2596): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _MyAccountState#f17df(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 2596): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 2596): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 2596): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 2596): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1167:9)
E/flutter ( 2596): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1202:6)
E/flutter ( 2596): #2      _MyAccountState.refresh (package:book_door/pages/my_account.dart:68:5)
E/flutter ( 2596): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2596):
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
D/MIUIInput( 2596): [KeyEvent] ViewRootImpl KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=138379287, downTime=138379287, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 }
D/MIUIInput( 2596): [KeyEvent] ViewRootImpl KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=138379287, downTime=138379287, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 }
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 2596): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Background concurrent copying GC freed 66283(2732KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(220KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 7553KB/14MB, paused 148us total 188.236ms
E/AndroidRuntime(32754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(32754): Process: com.goodix.fingerprint, PID: 32754
E/AndroidRuntime(32754): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.goodix.fingerprint.GoodixFingerprintApplication$BRecevier@1184971
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1457)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1652)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:726)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at com.goodix.fingerprint.GoodixFingerprintApplication.onLowMemory(GoodixFingerprintApplication.java:158)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLowMemory(ActivityThread.java:6464)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2111)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8069)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
E/AndroidRuntime(32754):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
W/kdoor.book_doo( 2596): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try solving these errors`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _MyAccountState#e5f00(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted) E/flutter ( 2596): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.`

You can solve them using the mounted property both in _MyAccountState and in the _CouponButtonState like this

```
if(mounted) {
setState(() {
        //
      });
}
```